# cannot convert int (*(int))(int) to int (*(int))(int)

Tags: c++, pointers

i'm trying to learn about function that returning a pointer to a function, after i tried to compile the code, it gives me this kind of error:

> cannot convert `int (*(int))(int)` to `int (*(int))(int)` in assignment.

I know those two `int (*(int))(int)` is the same thing, but why this error happens?

I'm using g++ to compile this code

```cpp
int sum(int i){
    return i+i;
}
int (*fp)(int) = sum;

int (*someFunc(int))(int a){
    return fp;
}

int main(){
    int i = 1;

    int (*fp2(int))(int);

    fp2 = someFunc;

    return 0;
}
```

I expect the fp2 will be a pointer to the fp variable, but it just giving me some error.

Any helps is appreciated, thank you

Comment: Copy and paste the actual error

Comment: Typedefs are super helpful when you're working with function pointers. It makes it a lot easier to read too.

Comment: funct.cpp:20:11: error: cannot convert ‘int (*(int))(int)’ to ‘int (*(int))(int)’ in assignment
@DetectivePikachu

Comment: Edited, i'm using cpp @EugeneSh.

Comment: What version of g++ are you using? I only get the "_error: assignment of function '`int (* fp2(int))(int)`'_"

Comment: i'm using 6.3.0 20170516 (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) version @AlgirdasPreidžius

Comment: Thank you for the advice @HSchmale, i will using typedef in the future

Comment: @topankentang In that case, you should've copied the entire error message, not just half of it.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius will do that in the future, thank you for the advice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You defined `fp2` as a function itself, not a pointer to a function, meaning you can't assign to it. You need to make it a pointer to a function:

```
int (*(*fp2)(int))(int);
fp2 = someFunc;
```

Better yet, use `typedef` so the code isn't super confusing:

```
typedef int func1(int);
typedef func1 *func2(int);

int sum(int i) {
    return i+i;
}

func1 *fp = sum;

func1 *someFunc(int a) {
    return fp;
}

int main() {
    int i = 1;
    func2 *fp2 = someFunc;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you mean the following

```
int (*( *fp2 ) (int))(int);

fp2 = someFunc;
```

that is fp2 should be declared as a pointer to function. Otherwise you are trying to apply the assignment operator to a function.

You could make the declarations simpler by introducing an alias.

For example

```
int sum(int i){
    return i+i;
}

using Fp = int( * )( int );

Fp fp = sum;

Fp someFunc(int){
    return fp;
}

int main() 
{
    Fp ( *fp2 ) (int);

    fp2 = someFunc;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It took me awhile to sort out the issues concerning function pointers, but I recommend the rules below: (a) Use a `typedef` statement for any user-defined storage class that allows each type to be treated as a single thing (e.g., `typedef struct _mystruct_ MyStruct;`). Following this shortcut makes possible: (b) Each part of the three-part expression (e.g., `RETURN-TYPE (POINTER-DECLARATION)(LIST-OF-ARGUMENT-TYPES);`) should contain **one set of parentheses** except for the leftmost term which contains **no parentheses**, and the middle term of the expression is the name of the variable (and therefore containers the asterisk[`*`]) for instance, `int (*_mainPtr)(int, const char *[]);` should define a pointer to the `main` function in your program.